# Strange UITable Separator issue - shifted right

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, xcode5

Got a bit of a weird one.

I am using the following codebase to build a `UItable` with `AutoLayout` programmatically:

[Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts & variable row heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights)

The issue I have is that the output seems to give me the separator shifted to the right I need the background to be the background colour you see, but that little "notch" still remains white. I have changed the  separator colour to black here for better viewing.

[image: Same output for Simulator and iOS Device]

Any ideas on what is creating that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in `viewDidLoad` method set:

```
self.tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

note, that this method available from iOS 7

Comment: Yup that did the job nicely! can't believe I missed that. I was messing about with self.tableView.backgroundcolor for zoo long! lol    Thanks mate